# How to get these symbols in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols, characters

In my book I found a few of weird symbols:

[image: E-like letter]

[image: P-like letter]

[image: H-like letter]

They are used as mark of ellipse, parabola and hyperbola, respectively (E-like, P-like and H-like letters in these images). How to get them in LaTeX (and by the way, what's their name)?

Comment: Are you looking for `\mathcal{E}`, `\mathcal{P}` and `\mathcal{H}`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The math alphabet `\mathcal` is used for these symbols:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[ \mathcal{E} \mathcal{P} \mathcal{H} \]

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]